# Is there any example/guide for handling session data in nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I m new to native script . I need a guide/example to mainitin **session data** for my subsequent requests . Is there any guide or git-hub project to maintain it ?

Answer (score 1):

you could use https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-localstorage for that. This plugin offers next to localstorage also access to session storage, a storage which is cleared when your app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

AceTheFace's solution is probably the most straightforward. You might also want to take a look at 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39465518/6647539

There are different ways to store data locally, and one might be better than the other, depending on your intended use, data complexity and expected "session" lifetime.